# Dell E6410 UEFI

Tags: laptop, uefi, bootloader

I'm having problems with my laptop using UEFI. What happens is, I can boot a UEFI operating system only if I go into boot options and manually select it. It will not automatically boot into any UEFI system (I've tried with both Debian and Windows 7).  If I let it go past the POST stage, I just get a blank screen indefinitely. I do have the UEFI boot options checked in the BIOS configuration (or whatever that's called now). Any help would be appreciated